# Why isn't my Image setting to a Square in my ImageView in Android?

Tags: android, imageview, drawrect, bitmapimage

I am trying to set an Image retrieved from my sdcard in a Square shape in an ImageView of 48 by 48dp. I have done the following coding but the Image still sets to Rectangle.Can anyone tell me step by step what to do?

```
  Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
  Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  Paint paint = new Paint();
  Canvas cc = new Canvas(myBitmap);
  cc.drawRect(48,48,48,48, paint);
  frndsimag.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: please post your xml file too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing, but the `ImageView` `frndsimag` could just have rectangular shape, and the image displayed would be stretching to fill the space.

Hard to say without seeing the layout xml, but you could try changing `frndsimag` `scaleType`, for instance.-

```
frndsimag.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
```

Comment: Thanx it worked with android:scaleType="centerCrop".

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 issues with this code. First of all, you are passing to ImageView original bitmap `bmp` instead `myBitmap`. Secondly, New bitmap has same size as original. If you didn't set android:scaleType for your ImageView it will use the same amount of space.

To achieve your goal I would do the following. Assuming you are defining ImageView in XML layout, set `android:width` and `android:height` to 48dp and `android:scaleType=fitXY` to fill entire space or `centerInside` if you wish to keep original ratio.

Then your code could be shrink to this:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
frndsimag.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

In case your images are large it would be wise to use optimization techniques from this page http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html